# We all have "a nose" or "noses"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Q1)

A. We all have a nose.

B. We all have noses.

Are they both equally fine?

Q2) When each of us has a bag and the bags are of the same kind,

A. We all have the same bag.

B. We all have the same bags.

Are they both fine?

Thank you.

Comment: *We **all** have **noses**, All of us have noses* or *We **each** have **a nose**, Each of us has a nose*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the word "all" singular or plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193125/is-the-word-all-singular-or-plural) See also ["Each of them is" or "each of them are"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83127/each-of-them-is-or-each-of-them-are)

Comment: No, it doesn't.  What I'm asking has nothing to do with the word, "all".

Comment: What I want to know is whether "We have a bag." and "We have bags." can have the same meaning or not.  This question has nothing to do with "all".

Comment: If this question has nothing to do with "all", why did you include ***all*** in your examples? You need to know that *by default* syntactically speaking, *We **all** have a nose* would mean that we collectively own a single nose (it's just that *semantically*, that doesn't make much sense). The "sensible" meaning is expressed by *We **each** have a nose*. Also, your *second* pair of examples are pointlessly confusing because the word ***same*** could either imply *multiple bags **of the same type*** OR *a **single** bag, collectively owned*.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know.  I was wondering if the sentence is pointlessly confusing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "[We all have a/an…](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we%20all%20have%20a%22&biw=1309&bih=697&tbm=nws&sxsrf=AOaemvLFZC85xgJQzhMb7mNMmNhAvh438Q%3A1640004394164&ei=KnvAYfquCYuQxc8PyNqz4Aw&ved=0ahUKEwj669-6tPL0AhULSPEDHUjtDMwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22we%20all%20have%20a%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LW5ld3MQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQkQIyBQgAEJECMgUIABCRAjIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABFDgBVjgBWDAB2gAcAB4AIABjQGIAd4BkgEDMS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-news)” is very common in English, for example:

> We all have a story / a threshold / a vested interest
> We all have a past / a dark side / a cross to bear
> We all have a role / a responsibility
> We all have an ego / an iPhone / an idea etc.

I'd prefer the singular "a nose" but everyone would understand (b) "We all have noses" because our life experience tells us that humans don't have two or more noses. A less ambiguous statement would be

- Everyone has a nose
- Each one of us has a nose

However the OP's second example,  "We all have the same bags", needs clarification because it *could* suggest that each person is carrying  two or more bags that are identical.

Comment: Do you have a preference between "We each have a nose" and "We all have a nose"? To me, the latter literally means that we all share one nose, and only from the ridiculous meaning it's understood to mean the former.

Comment: @gotube "We each have a nose", "Each one of us has a nose" and  "Everyone has a nose" are probably the best. I suppose interpreting "we all have a nose" *could* mean we all share the same nose but I have never understood it that way. Likewise one could think "We all have noses" the same way as "We all have eyes"  or "ears" suggesting that we have more than one nose.